# What should you do if someone is eluding confirmation in writing?

Tags: landlord

Problem 1 and 2 have appeared in a rented home in Ontario, Canada.
The builder will fix Problem 1, but not Problem 2.

A landlord and you correspond by email. You asked him by email to confirm his reading and receiving your email (call this E) in which you explain your innocence for either problem. which he must have received, because he telephoned you to argue that you are responsible for Problem 2.
I do not plan to telephone with him ever again.

Although you and he still continue to email, he has not acknowledged E in writing, possibly to elude leaving written evidence. Now the landlord emails you asking you to confirm when workers hired by the building can come to fix Problem 1. He has said nothing about Problem 2.

What should you do now? Do you need his confirmation in writing of email E? I am afraid that without his confirmation of E, he can argue later never to have received my defense of innocence.

Comment: Just write him a clear email about #2 only...

Comment: If problem #1 and #2 were the body of a single email and you have a Reply of that email talking about #2, I don't think he can claim not to have been notified about problem #1 at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuff email, write him a letter and send it certified mail (or confirmed delivery or whatever the equivalent is where you live).

Of course, this won't help if the landlord is right and Problem 2 really is you issue to deal with. In any event you need to resolve the dispute: win or lose, a resolved dispute is better than an unresolved one.